# had been working vs was working

Tags: grammar

> (1) I **had been working** in the garden when she arrived, so I didn't
> hear her come in.
>
> (2) I **was working** in the garden when she arrived, so I didn't hear
> her come in.

I think that past perfect continuous in (1) only refers to an action from the past up to/until the past point in time ( she arrived). We don't know if I was still working at the time she came in.

I think that present continuous in (2) refers to an ongoing action at the past point ( she arrived). We know that I was still working when she came in.

So, I think that using the present continuous as in (2) is more correct than using the present perfect continuous in (1).
Are my opinions correct?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, (2) is the simplest and most natural way to say it.

(1) could be understood to mean that the speaker had finished working, so they might have stayed in the garden or gone back indoors.

The past perfect continuous could also have been used to speak of a time before another past time.

> When I went into the house I was surprised to find Mary there. I had been working in the garden when she arrived, so I hadn't heard her come in.

Comment: In your example:… I had been working in the garden when she arrived, so I hadn't heard her come in.=> it doesn’t necessarily mean that I am still in progress of working when she came. Right?

Comment: It means that I **was** still working when she arrived, but I'm now talking about the time after I finished work and went back indoors.

Comment: If so, with my example, using past perfect continuous also means  I am still was in progress of working when she came. Right?

Comment: "I am still was" makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, I meant “I was still in progress…”

Comment: The continuous tenses always refer to an activity in progress (continuing!).

Comment: But does the action still happening in the present?

Comment: Sorry, But with the past perfect continuous, does the action was still happening in the past point ( at the point when she came) ?

Comment: You should say _was the action still happening?_ Yes, the point is that the speaker didn't hear the woman enter the house because he was busy working in the garden.

Comment: In my example, we know that I was still working thanks to the sentence “I didn’t hear her come in”. The past  perfect continuous “I had been working “ itself doesn’t let us know if I still was working at that time. Am I right?

Comment: _I had been working_ is the **past** perfect continuous.  Its exact meaning depends on the context of the sentence it is used in.